# Is this proper use of MVVM when trying to create a new window based on a item in a ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I'm currently playing around with WPF and MVVM and I've been trying to find a way to select an item in a list and display it in a new window. And I came up with a solution that I personally like but I'm not sure if it follows a valid MVVM architecture.

So I have my `MainWindow.xaml`

```xml
<Window x:Class="Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Views" 
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Views.MVVM.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Background="#252525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkObjects}"
                  Style="{StaticResource ListStyle}"
                  Name="MainList"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Which uses this style that binds each item in the collection and also applies a `MouseBinding` which allows me to `LeftDoubleClick` the item to invoke a command.
I pass the the entire object as a command parameter because that's the `DataContext`.
And this is needed for the new Window.

```xml
<Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="ListStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel Margin="2">
                    <DockPanel.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                                      Command="{Binding DisplayItemCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                    </DockPanel.InputBindings>
                    <DockPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#303030"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                               AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, 
                                                               Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="MediumSpringGreen"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DockPanel.Style>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NetworkModel.Address}" Foreground="Black"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `MainViewModel` does nothing but generate some dummy data in the constructor. This is where I start doubting whether or not this is valid MVVM, because I'm generating objects that are not based on a `Model` but rather an entire `ViewModel` which in theory makes sense, but I'm not sure.

```
public ObservableCollection<NetworkObjectViewModel> NetworkObjects { get; set; }
public MainViewModel()
{
    NetworkObjects = new ObservableCollection<NetworkObjectViewModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        NetworkObjects.Add(new NetworkObjectViewModel() { NetworkModel = new NetworkModel { Address = $"Address {i}", Port = i } });
    }
}
```

And the `NetworkObjectViewModel` contains a `RelayCommand` and  `NetworkModel`.

```
public class NetworkObjectViewModel
{
    public NetworkModel NetworkModel { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand DisplayItemCommand { get; set; }

    public NetworkObjectViewModel()
    {
        DisplayItemCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            WindowService.ShowWindow(o);
        });
    }
}
```

The `WindowService` is simple, it just creates a new `GenericWindow` and sets it `DataContext` so that it can make a decision and display the correct `UserControl` based on the `DataContext`

```
internal class WindowService
{
    public static void ShowWindow(object DataCtx)
    {
        var t  = new GenericWindow();
        t.DataContext = DataCtx;
        t.Show();
    }
}
```

And here's the `GenericWindow.xaml`

```xml
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:NetworkObjectViewModel}">
            <v:TestView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:NetworkObjectViewModel2}">
            <v:TestView2/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding .}" />
```

And the `TestView.xaml` which is  nothing but a simple `UserControl` that looks like this

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding NetworkModel.Address, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               Width="100"
               Height="25"
               IsEnabled="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: To make it short: yes :o)

Comment: This is how I'd implement as well (it makes sense from a data flow's point of view). So yeah, I would say this looked okay.

Comment: let me guess: NetworkObjectViewModel, GenericWindow and WindowService are all in one and the same project?

Comment: @ASh That is correct!

Comment: @JohnA, then you don't have MVVM architecture, because you can't separate view and viewmodels into different projects (because of cyclic dependencies: GenericWindow references NetworkObjectViewModel , NetworkObjectViewModel references WindowService, WindowService references GenericWindow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is where I start doubting whether or not this is valid MVVM, because I'm generating objects that are not based on a Model but rather an entire ViewModel which in theory makes sense, but I'm not sure.

This makes perfect sense.

The model in MVVM typically refers to types that you don't want to bind to directly, such as for example data transfer objects (DTOs), domain objects that contain business logic or even services or repositories.

Creating and exposing a collection of "child" view models to bind to from a "parent" view model class is a perfectly fine and a common approach.